# How should I align top and bottom image which forms one continuous single image?

Tags: c++, image-processing, fftw

I have two X-ray images of same person which were scanned from film plates which were kept vertically one below the other. I have to form a single image by stitching two images. Ideally I would blindly join two images one below other but this is not the case. Due to scanning of plates separately, I am getting some Left Right misalignment. Hence the question is how should I align two images programmatically?

Here is the image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how it was scanned you might also have rotation.  Ideally you have some overscan, and you have some kind of markings (2 at least) in that overscan area that you look for in the images, and when you find them, you can reposition/rotate one of the images to match up the markings.  If you don't have markings or overscan, you job will be much much tougher... maybe lines for the edges of the images?

Comment: I think I don't have to rotate bottom image by any chance. Just wanted some algorithm to shift bottom image left or right so that it aligns with top image. I do not have any markings as well.

Comment: You'll have to get into more advanced image processing to accomplish this.  I'm not sure if you'll have a general case (i.e. in this one you have a distinct near-vertical lines that make it more obvious), but in this case, you could run an edge detection algorithm then running some analysis on those results, make sure any edges that transition through the bottom of the top image into the top of the bottom image line up...